# Naming Optional Parameters in Visual Basic

Tags: vb6, optional-arguments

In Visual Basic, I have functions with a lot of optional arguments. I would like to be able to pass just a few of these optional arguments to a function without having to use numerous commas and spaces to get to the ones I want. Somewhere I saw a way to named params such as `OptVar:=val`, but that does not seem to work. Just wondering if there is a way to do this. This would help readability.

```
Function foo(Optional val1 = 1, Optional val2 = 2, Optional val3 = 3) 
End Function
```

To use `foo` with only the last arg needed like this:

```
fud = foo( , , 4)
```

is a little unwieldy. It would be better if a construct like this worked:

```
fud = foo(val3:=4)
```

But this does not work.

Comment: It is easier to give an answer if you provide some code that you have tried.

Comment: Function foo(Optional val1 = 1, Optional val2 = 2, Optional val3 = 3)  
  ...  
End Function  
  
To use foo with only the last arg needed like this: fud = foo( , , 4)  
is a little unweildy. It would be better if a construct like this worked:  fud = foo(val3:=4).  But this does not work.  
It would be great if something like this would work!  
Thanks.

Comment: It has been awhile, looks like nobody can find a solution for this.  
Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 4):

This actually do work:

```
Function foo(Optional val1 = 1, Optional val2 = 2, Optional val3 = 3)
    MsgBox "val1: " & val1 & " val2: " & val2 & " val3: " & val3
    foo = val3
End Function


Private Sub Form_Load()
    MsgBox "foo returned: " & foo(val3:=4)
End Sub
```

You will have as output a first messagebox saying *"val1: 1 val2: 2 val3: 4"* and a second one with *foo returned: 4*